# Copy and rename files - Linux cp command

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix

I have the following files in my directory.

```
    tom_aaa.txt  
    tom_bbb.txt  
    tom_ccc.txt
```

I want to copy these files and rename them by replacing tom with jerry using shell command (MAC / LINUX /UNIX)

**Expected result:**

```
tom_aaa.txt  
tom_bbb.txt  
tom_ccc.txt  
jerry_aaa.txt  
jerry_bbb.txt  
jerry_ccc.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this.

```
for i in `ls *`; do cp $i `echo $i | sed "s/tom/jerry/g"`; done
```